# Determining type of clicked object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking a way of determining the type object I clicked in JavaScript.

I populated in React (with PrimeReact - [Tree View](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tree)) a GUI element similar to a Tree View with a JSon object from a Rest call. Now the first layer of the Tree is from ObjectA and 2nd layer from ObjectB.

When user clicks, I don't want to raise events for ObjectA but only for ObjectB, so if I would do in Java, I would do something like following

```
ClickedObject.isAssignable(ObjectB)
```

which would tell me this is the type of the object I am interested.

I tried to do something like

```
ObjectB instanceof ClassB
```

but while I constructed the object from JSon, I don't have an access to its constructor (or is there a way to get the constructor of an object)..

What would be the best way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You don't click on JavaScript objects: you click HTML elements in the DOM.

Comment: In my view this is a highly complicated way of thinking about user interfaces and JavaScript. If you want to know what you clicked on, just pass that as an argument in your React components click handler, problem solved.

Comment: I pass the object as argument in the click event, but user can click the two objects, so I can get ObjectA and ObjectB, which are two different types, and I don't want to create the events delivering ObjectA.

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  outer = (e) => {
    console.log('outer');
  } 

  inner = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('inner');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.outer}>
        Outer
        <div onClick={this.inner}>Inner</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/j2j6x0lo6w

Or:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  click = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="outer" onClick={this.click}>
        Outer
        <div id="inner" onClick={this.click}>Inner</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Or:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  click(id, e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={(e) => this.click('outer', e)}>
        Outer
        <div onClick={(e) => this.click('inner', e)}>Inner</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

**Edit**

For the PrimeReact Tree component, you could do an object reference equality check. For example:

```
onSelectionChange(e) {
  if (e.selection === data[1].children[2]) {
    console.log('Clicked the 3rd child of the second parent');
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, first all thx for the answer, I understand what you mean and I can use your solutions, if I would have the full control of the Component\Class but I am using PrimeReact Tree Component and it is not letting me assign special callbacks\event handler on specific nodes. It has the following structure '<Tree value={data} selectionMode="single" selectionChange={this.onSelectionChange.bind(this)}></Tree>' so it is calling onSelectionChange for every node and pass the clicked node, so I have to find a way to figure out a way to distinguish the node and I don't want to do string comparisons.

Comment: Inside your `onSelectionChange(e)` handler, you can do something like: `if (e.selection === myTreeData[1].children[2]) { ...`. So just do a reference equality check on the object to see if it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [Primereact tree node](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tree) object, you'll notice that there is `data` property. You can use it to achieve what you want.

Fox example, populate list of nodes on the following way

```
    var data = [
        {
            "label": "Documents",
            "data": "ObjectA",
            "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
            "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
            "children": [{
                "label": "Work",
                "data": "ObjectB",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder"
            },
            {
                "label": "Work",
                "data": "ObjectB",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder"
            }]
      }];
```

(1st level nodes have `data: "ObjectA"`, 2nd level nodes have `data: "ObjectB"`,..)

Now you can check selected "object type" inside function `onSelectionChange` like this

```
onSelectionChange(e) {
    console.log("Node selected");
    console.log(e); //check out console to see structure of 'e'
    if (e.selection.data == 'ObjectA'){
        console.log("ObjectA selected");
    } else if (e.selection.data == 'ObjectB'){
        console.log("ObjectB selected");
    } else {
        console.log("Unknown object type selected");
    }
}
```

Please note that you can assign **any type** to `data` property and build more complex data structure representing Primereact tree node.